# Formato de salida de fecha con DateFormat

Tags: java, date

Quiero tener el siguiente formato de fecha al realizar un `System.out.println()`: `31/03/2016`.

Como me pasan el formato en un tipo String de esta forma `"31-03-2016"`, utilizo las clases

```
import java.util.Date;

import java.text.DateFormat;

java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
```

para darle formato correcto, y utilizo esta forma:

```
SimpleDateFormat d = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
Date date = d.parse("31-03-2016");
System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(date));
```

Pero me muestra: `31-03-2016`

Comment: Debes colocar en el constructor el formato `SimpleDateFormat`. Para iniciar con ese formato. SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ya que el standard de tu sistema es con guiones, necesitas 2 `SimpleDateFormat`:

- uno para parsear (convertir el `String` a `Date`)
- otro para formatear (convertir `Date` a `String` en el formato deseado)

Tu codigo será algo así:

```
// el que parsea
SimpleDateFormat parseador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
// el que formatea
SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");

Date date = parseador.parse("31-03-2016");
System.out.println(formateador.format(date));
```

**SALIDA**

```
31/03/16
```

**[DEMO ONLINE](https://ideone.com/dIGGmQ)**

---

## AÑADIDOS

> De todas formas, no entiendo porque no funciona `DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(this.date)` y me muestra `31-mar-2016` ya que utilizo un Windows 7 64bits Español, y mi formato de fecha es: `dd/MM/aaaa`

Pasa porque usas Java 7 o superior, a partir de esta version se cambio la manera en que `Locale.getDefault()` funciona.

Para resumir, tienes que modificar no solo el formato de la region, sino tambien cambiar el modo en que el idioma muestra las fechas.

Puede comprobar el problema en este [**bug**](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7073906) reportado

[**FUENTE (EN)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7107972/java-7-default-locale/8319889#8319889)

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Comment: De todas formas, no entiendo porque no funciona `DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(this.date)` y me muestra `31-mar-2016` ya que utilizo  un Windows 7 64bits Español, y mi formato de fecha es: `dd/MM/aaaa`.

Comment: @jmgc1982 mirate la edición y los links que he colgado y no dudes en preguntar si te queda alguna duda

Comment: Ya me funciona gracias a tu código de ejemplo. Mil gracias!