# Formatear Fecha de "dd-MM-yy" a "yyyy-MM-dd" en Java

Tags: java

necesito darle formato a una fecha que estoy recibiendo de un String.
Lo recibo de la siguiente manera: "17-04-19" y quiero que se vea de la siguiente manera "2019-04-17".
Espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: lo normal es dia mes y año te la da correctamente porque no te vale asi? dime de donde sale dame codigo y te intento echar una mano. Como no pongas codigo de donde viene y eso te inflaran a negrativos

Comment: Lo recibo a través de una comunicación serial por Bluetooth, y quiero darle el formato porque así es como me lo solicita el servicio web que consumo, pero ya lo he solucionado, gracias.

Comment: Agrega el código que estés tratando por favor, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 2):

La manera más sencilla de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
Date date = format.parse(TuFecha);
```

De la clase `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. Donde la variable `TuFecha` la reemplazas por el valor de la fecha que desees.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;  //clase para formatear fechas y horas
import java.time.LocalDate;  //clase para representar fechas.

public class Demo {

    static DateTimeFormatter formatoDeEntrada = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yy");
    static DateTimeFormatter formatoDeSalida = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");


    public String convierte(String fechaEnTexto) {
        LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.parse(fechaEnTexto, formatoDeEntrada);
        return fecha.format(formatoDeSalida);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo tendrias que poner algo así:

```
SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
String strDate = date.format("12/05/2022");//Dentro del .format() coloca tu variable tipo Date
strDate= "2022/05/12";//Resultado
```

Answer (score -1):

Para aquel que lo requiera pude solucionarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
String newDate = formatDate("17-04-19");

public String formatDate(String oldDate) {
        SimpleDateFormat parseador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
        SimpleDateFormat formateador = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date date = null;
        try {
            date = parseador.parse(oldDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return formateador.format(date);
    }
```

Obteniendo como resultado "2019-04-17".

Tomé como ejemplo lo descrito en la siguiente pregunta: [Formato de salida de fecha con DateFormat](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6707/formato-de-salida-de-fecha-con-dateformat)